# Hi, I am facing an issue in opening popups in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, popup, cypress

My code

```
 <a href ="xyz.com" onclick="javascript:AddData();">
Add
</a>
```

In application side a pop up is opened on clicking the Add button instead of new page load.

Now If I am performing a click operation in cypress by
cy.get('a').contains('Add').click()
It clicks the add button but it redirects to the link in href tag instead of opening the popup.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you manually click on the button on the cypress chrome and check what's the behavior? - A popup or a redirection.

Comment: @AlapanDas Its a redirection. I have tried invoke('removeAttr','href') but its not working

Comment: Hey if you are getting a redirection then you should check for a redirection, Right and not  a pop up ?

Comment: @AlapanDas But in application side a pop up opens on clicking Add and on cypress the redirection happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<a href ="javascript:AddData();">
Add
</a>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your suggestion.
I am working on cypress and I can not change the code. I am not a developer.